# Include line of text in HTML e-mail based on value of cell

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I have a template with an HTML body. I want to include a line depending on the value of the Value of cell F.

If in cell F it is written "incomplete" then it shall include the phrase "Your payment is incomplete" into the e-mail text.

If in cell F it is written "complete" a space is added to the HMTL body.

How can I achieve this?

```
With OutMail
.To = Cells(cell.Row, "C").Value
.Subject = "Request" & Cells(cell.Row, "E").Value
.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
.HTMLBody = Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value & Cells(cell.Row, "B").Value _
& "<p>The status of your invoice is</p>" _

If (Cells(cell.Row, "F").Value) = "incomplete" then: 
.HTMLBody = "<p> Your payment is incomplete<p/>"  _

Else 
 .HTMLBody = "<p>  <p/>" _
& "<p>Thank you</p>" _
```

Answer (score 0):

Vba if loop looks like this.

```
If condition
    'if true
Else
    'if false
EndIf
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few mistakes in your code and some things creates confusion. First, the if statements. Write them like this, instead:

```
If (Cells(cell.Row, "F").Value) = "incomplete" Then 
    .HTMLBody = "<p> Your payment is incomplete<p/>"
Else 
    .HTMLBody = "<p>  <p/>" & _
                "<p>Thank you</p>"
End If
```

Second, your cell references are not correct. Columns are referenced by numbers in the Cells method (i.e F=6). It is also risky to expect that the active sheet is the expected sheet. Create a reference to it to make sure

```
Dim TargetSheet as WorkSheet
Set TargetSheet = Worksheets("MySheet")
TargetSheet.Cells(cell.Row, 6).Value
```

Answer (score 0):

use [IIF()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/iif-function) function

```
With OutMail
    .To = Cells(cell.Row, "C").value
    .Subject = "Request" & Cells(cell.Row, "E").value
    .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
    .HTMLBody = Cells(cell.Row, "A").value & Cells(cell.Row, "B").value _
                & "<p>The status of your invoice is</p>" _
                & IIf(Cells(cell.Row, "F").value = "incomplete", "<p> Your payment is incomplete<p/>", "<p>  <p/><p>Thank you</p>")
End With
```

just adjust the two *results* of the function to your needs: as it is now, it adds either `"<p> Your payment is incomplete<p/>"` or `"<p>  <p/><p>Thank you</p>"`, in relation of `Cells(cell.Row, "F").value`matching *"incomplete"* or not

Comment: That is awesome! Thank you - that helped a lot!  But I have another small problem... if I want to add & "<p>The status of your invoice is</p>" & Cells(cell.Row, "F").Value it causing a problem because of the " between the F.. Is there any other solution how to reference a cell?

Comment: I'm not getting you: please be more specific as to where  do you want to add  `& "<p>The status of your invoice is</p>" & Cells(cell.Row, "F").Value`